Do I want new Chrome
I have Gnome (newest Ubuntu software) Google says it is now unsupported and to re-install it. Why would I reinstall unsupported Chrome? It also says there is a new Chrome--should I install it? Is it compatible with Gnome?

This question is similar to: How to install Google Chrome. The top upvoted answer tells how to install Google Chrome so that it will be updated automatically. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
